# Principle Component Analysis (PCA) Explained Variance remains the same after changing dataframe position

Tags: scikit-learn, pca

I have a dataframe where A and B is used to predict C

```
df = df[['A','B','C']]
array = df.values

X = array[:,0:-1]
Y = array[:,-1]

# Feature Importance
model = GradientBoostingClassifier()
model.fit(X, Y)
print ("Importance:")
print((model.feature_importances_)*100)


#PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=len(df.columns)-1)
fit = pca.fit(X)

print("Explained Variance")
print(fit.explained_variance_ratio_)
```

This prints

```
Importance:
[ 53.37975706  46.62024294]
Explained Variance
[ 0.98358394  0.01641606]
```

However when I changed the dataframe position swapping A and B, only the importance changed, but the Explain variance remains, why did the explained variance not change according to [0.01641606 0.98358394]?

```
df = df[['B','A','C']]


Importance:
[ 46.40771024  53.59228976]
Explained Variance
[ 0.98358394  0.01641606]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explained variance does not refer to A or B or any columns of your dataframe. It refers to the principal components identified by the PCA, which are some linear combinations of the columns. These components are sorted in the order of decreasing variance as the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) says:

> components_ : array, shape (n_components, n_features)
>   Principal axes in feature space, representing the directions of maximum variance in the data. The components are sorted by explained_variance_.
>
> explained_variance_ : array, shape (n_components,)
>   The amount of variance explained by each of the selected components.
>   Equal to n_components largest eigenvalues of the covariance matrix of X.
>
> explained_variance_ratio_ : array, shape (n_components,)
>   Percentage of variance explained by each of the selected components.

So, the order of features does not affect the order of components returned. It does affect the array `components_` which is a matrix that can be used to map principal components to the feature space.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, now I am thinking the only way to sort which are the important features to keep will be to use (model.feature_importances_) since the Explained Variance does not sort it for me

Comment: There are many things you can do with these tools, if you know what they actually do. As you could notice, there is no Y parameter in PCA, so your Y data was not even used by it. PCA is not about predicting Y based on X.